# Change Slicer Value in dropdown monthly to quarterly in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI report in which i want users to select "Period Type" in drop down. and when they chose values like **Monthly** or **quarterly** it should dynamically change the slicer values to  monthly or quarterly.

example is given below.
When Period Type Is Selected To Montlhy

https://pasteboard.co/IYuYSO2.png

When Period Type Is Selected To Quarterly

https://pasteboard.co/IYuYcVw.png

And i have data set with DimDate Table and FactSales Table. Both are joined Table with One to Many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks tailor made for a visual from the marketplace. Check the following link out:

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380786?tab=Overview

This slicer will let you choose the frequency and then your slicer will change to reflect that. You can download this from the marketplace. If you have not done this before, you can do this by selecting "Import from marketplace" option after clicking on the 3 dots at the end of the Visualization tab. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not something which i'm looking for. actually i am trying to get a way to do this using DAX or any other solution.

Comment: This visual surely does the Job but my filter pane is too small for this visual